# Is that possible to get youtube broadcast or livestream status without access_key

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I would like to load the livestream into my live list when the status is live without using the access key.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

> You need a Google Account to access the Google Developers Console, request an API key, and register your application.
>   Register your application with Google so that it can submit API requests.
>   After registering your application, select the YouTube Data API as one of the services that your application uses:
>   Go to the Developers Console and select the project that you just registered.
>   Open the API Library in the Google Developers Console. If prompted, select a project or create a new one. In the list of APIs, make sure the status is ON for the YouTube Data API v3 and, if you are a YouTube Content Partner, the YouTube Content ID API.
>   [Source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started)